# Compare Vectors of different types in Java

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I have two Java vectors initialized like these:

```
Integer intArr[] = {100, 200, 300};
Double doubleArr[] = {100.0, 200.0, 300.0};

Vector<Integer> vInt = new Vector<Integer>(Arrays.asList(intArr));
Vector<Double> vDouble = new Vector<Double>(Arrays.asList(doubleArr));
```

The comparision that I do is like this

```
boolean equal = vInt.equals(vDouble);  //equal = false
```

How can I compare the two vectors and get `true` as result considering that, despite the different types, the vectors have the same values?

TIA,

Comment: It what case would any element from `vDouble` be considered equal to anything in `vInt`?

Comment: Well, when (100, 200, 300) = (100.0, 200.0, 300.0). They have different types, but their values are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the comparison yourself. Note this is subject to conversion errors, for example after around 2<sup>53</sup> `double` can no longer represent odd numbers. So I don't recommend comparing `long` to `double`, for example.

```
public static boolean numericEquals(
    Collection<? extends Number> c1,
    Collection<? extends Number> c2
) {
    if(c1.size() != c2.size())
        return false;
    if(c1.isEmpty())
        return true;

    Iterator<? extends Number> it1 = c1.iterator();
    Iterator<? extends Number> it2 = c2.iterator();

    while(it1.hasNext()) {
        if(it1.next().doubleValue() != it2.next().doubleValue())
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no choice but to compare each element in turn; a generic solution would look something like this:

```
public static boolean compareArrays(List<Integer> vInt, List<Double> vDouble) {
    if (vInt.size() != vDouble.size())
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < vInt.size(); i++) {
        Integer iVal = vInt.get(i);
        Double  dVal = vDouble.get(i);
        if (!iVal.equals(dVal))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

As a side note - you shouldn't be using `Vector`, unless you really, really need the access to be synchronized, you should use an `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: I'm using `Vector` because I'm developing a class that gets data from Lotus Notes. The data comes as `Vector` when is an array, but thank you for the advice :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to do this. The values 100.0 and 100 are NOT equal. You will have to subclass Vector and override equals. Inside your equals method, you'll need to adhere to the general contract of equals for Vector, but you'll have to perform some comparison operation like the following:

```
if(vInt.size() == vDouble.size()){
    for(int index = 0; index < vInt.size()){
        if(vInt.get(index) - (int) vDouble.get(index) == 0){
             //etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in this comparison, `100 - (int) 100.4d` would evaluate to `true`.

Comment: This is completely wrong syntax, Java vectors don't work like this.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Thanks. Array in post title got me confused.

Comment: @mttdbrd: sorry for the title. I fixed it and improved the example.

Answer (score 0):

I think it needs to be iterated and compare like below.

```
package org.owls.compare;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer intArr[] = {100, 200, 300};
        Double doubleArr[] = {100.d, 200.0, 300.0};
        Vector<Integer> v1 = new Vector<Integer>(Arrays.asList(intArr));
        Vector<Double> v2 = new Vector<Double>(Arrays.asList(doubleArr));
        boolean isSame = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++){
            int dval = (int)((double)v2.get(i));
            if(!v1.get(i).equals(dval)){
                isSame = false;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("result >> " + isSame);
    }
}
```